# Show next available date from list in excel?

Tags: excel

I've got a dynamic list of dates in rows as follows.  Lets say this is column L

```
01-Jan-12   
01-Apr-12   
01-Jul-12   
01-Oct-12   
01-Jan-13
```

Basically, what I wanted to do was to show the next date that is upcoming, or if there is no date in the future, show the last date.  Ie. As it is current January 8th, it would display 01-Jan-13.  If we were in May 2012, it would display 01-July-12

I am currently using:

```
=MIN(IF($L$4:$L$19>TODAY(),!$L$4:$L$19))
```

Which works, as long as there is a date in the future.  Otherwise it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Excel? In Excel **2007** or later you can use `IFERROR`, e.g.

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($L$4:$L$19>TODAY(),$L$4:$L$19),1),MAX($L$4:$L$19))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

or a "non-array" version

`=IFERROR(INDEX($L$4:$L$19,MATCH(TODAY(),$L$4:$L$19)+1),MAX($L$4:$L$19))`